# Why Rolling Wavelet (Using Pywavelet Package) Is Not Casual?

Tags: time-series, wavelet, pywavelets

summarily and Clearly Speaking, There is a Time series Data Set (Suppose 1000 Sample), I take 100 first sample (0 to 99) and get wavelet and reconstruct it (or equivalently, denoise it), Next Shift the window by 1 (1 to 100) and do so again, Just Like Move Mean Algorithm.
But There is an issue, I see high fluctuation in the signal edge (see red rectangle in below figure).
**What is the cause of this phenomena?
**# **Is This a regular behavior?**

## Or What is wrong?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOjKs.png)

How can I get rolling wavelet?

Comment: Welcome to SO @mohammad. Could you please share a code example with us? You may edit your original post to include your script.

Comment: Without seeing the code, my best guess is that it's because there are not enough signal points left for all filter coefficients (e.g. when you have a filter length of 10 and are 3 positions away from the end). A common solution is to wrap around, so after signal point `x[n-1]` go back to `x[0]`. As you can see, in your example `x[0]` is much higher than `x[n-1]` so that may explain the higher signal in your reconstruction. In other words, you *do* have e 'rolling' wavelet, if that means going from `n-1` back to `0`. There is Not Much Clarity without showing the code though.